# xcodebuild destination unavailable despite being correct

Tags: xcode, gitlab, continuous-integration, ios-simulator, continuous-deployment

I am configuring an app's CI/CD pipeline through GitLab, but the following command in my build stage:

```
xcodebuild build -project Workspaces.xcodeproj -scheme Workspaces -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=0AC6CCC9-8002-494E-95E2-5B4B975EC36B,OS=14.1,name=iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)' | xcpretty -s
```

...produces an error stating that the destination simulator isn't available, despite listing that specific simulator as available.

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
61      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0AC6CCC9-8002-494E-95E2-5B4B975EC36B, OS:14.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
62  The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.
63  Available destinations for the "Workspaces" scheme:
64      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:81BDC474-B2C1-48BE-91CB-0950277EDD42, OS:15.0, name:iPad (7th generation) }
65      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:836A0981-32C3-4C60-B595-D1B6C5F7E615, OS:14.1, name:iPad (8th generation) }
66      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F0F51C32-9B0A-495F-9D38-4B633529D66D, OS:15.0, name:iPad (8th generation) }
67      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7A183F12-CB11-472D-8ED2-D4D24CB267FC, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
68      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6EF4B3C5-9E9A-46D5-AB61-381F3E93DF47, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (3rd generation) }
69      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:52B30717-C6A6-46FF-A6B1-5D0F38AA48FB, OS:14.1, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
70      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AFC3B7A5-9903-4090-BD61-F35CC76B16D1, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
71      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:66DB8B90-2F45-4CC3-95F0-D20015BEB812, OS:14.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
72      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4F04B90A-7FD5-492C-B994-B0B0F1C53B22, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
73      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:04454289-475B-4A67-B64A-4BDE8AB146E2, OS:14.1, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) }
74      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:894AD58D-72D8-4299-B449-11D34F82F609, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) }
75      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BB791183-6A1C-4768-8765-BC627A7BA7E2, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
76      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0AC6CCC9-8002-494E-95E2-5B4B975EC36B, OS:14.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
77      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BAD0DEA0-0160-4C4E-B587-F3F58DC30B23, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
78      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:687158D4-B203-4DCD-B79D-E69DE257ACDF, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
79      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AAA5737C-E5A8-41A7-AF51-B3C3AF3FA315, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
80      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9DBD0F3B-5B12-4C16-8523-A02DA190FEC0, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
81  Ineligible destinations for the "Workspaces" scheme:
82      { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
83      { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
```

And then I'm left with the very unhelpful error message in GitLab's console print out of: `ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this required removing the id key/value pair from the destination string, which makes sense as the command is then more generic and not tied to a single simulator (a simulator on another build machine will have a different id):

```
xcodebuild build -project Workspaces.xcodeproj -scheme Workspaces -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=14.1,name=iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)' | xcpretty -s
```

Would be super cool if Xcode's error message was actually helpful. A boy can dream.